# Phantom triangles on downvote warning

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There are phantom triangles on top of the warning bubble when low-rep users downvote a post:

[image: screencap documenting the graphical artifacts]

I'm running Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Would seem to be the same issue as [CSS bleed-thru on tags](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2418/354) . I thought I saw on Meta Stack Exchange that this was fixed. (Let me see if I can track down that post.)

Comment: Ah, yes. See also: [CSS z-index causes part of tags to show through notifications on webmasters, web applications, gaming, and gamedev](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243133/21960)

Comment: Since the site has been redesigned, this question is moot.

Answer (score 3):

[Geoff Dalgas♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) says [this issue has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243133/css-z-index-causes-part-of-tags-to-show-through-notifications-on-webmasters-web/250700#250700):

> You have caught my attention on this one. A fix has been pushed and will build out soon. I also want you to know that our design team has been hard at work at converting all of our .less files to a consistent and uniform layout which will solve most of these issues in the future. Thanks for the report and we'll keep you posted on the status of the conversion.